# Why cant I connect to replica set using mongo shell?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I can connect to replica set using following command from mongo shell version 3.2.11. But the same does not works with mongo shell v3.4.1.

```
mongo --host \
      "replicaSet1/10.10.10.15:27001,10.10.10.16:27002,10.10.10.17:27000" mydbname \
      -u root -p root \
      --authenticationDatabase admin

 [main] Error: Failed to parse mongodb:// URL: mongodb://replicaSet1/10.10.10.15:27001,10.10.10.16:27002,10.10.10.17:27000/mydbname :
```

I have read [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#cmdoption--host) that replica set address format has not changed since v 3.4.1 release.

Why cant I connect to db ? What is the parse error, as per new format(if its there).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a known regression in MongoDB 3.4.0/3.4.1: [SERVER-27289: `mongo --host replSet/Host:Port` no longer works](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-27289). A fix has been committed for the upcoming MongoDB 3.4.2 release.

You can work around this in an affected 3.4.x `mongo` shell by using the standard [MongoDB Connection String URI](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#standard-connection-string-format) format instead:

```
mongo --host mongodb://10.10.10.15:27001,10.10.10.16:27002,10.10.10.17:27000/mydbname?replicaSet=replicaSet1
```

You can also use a standard MongoDB Connection String as a plain argument (i.e. without the `--host` parameter):

```
mongo mongodb://10.10.10.15:27001,10.10.10.16:27002,10.10.10.17:27000/mydbname?replicaSet=replicaSet1
```

> I have read here that replica set address format has not changed since v 3.4.1 release.

Support for using the standard MongoDB Connecting String format in the `--host` parameter was added in MongoDB 3.4 in order to align the `mongo` shell connection string syntax with the format used by all official drivers.

This change is currently not noted in the MongoDB 3.4 manual, so I've raised [DOCS-9808](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-9808) to clarify.

Comment: which is the difference between `replicaSet1` and `replset`? You have to put replica set twice?

Comment: @FacundoChambo Oops .. transcription fail. Good catch! I've fixed the examples as the replicaSet name only needs to appear once.